# Oracle Forms 10 / java

Tags: java, oracleforms

Is it possible for a java application, called by Oracle Forms, to participate in the same database session like Forms?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is for the java application to run as a component of a form, e.g. as a java bean within a form container.

Comment: Looks like Sten has shot down this idea. I think the best option then might be for the java bean to delegate all SQL to the Form.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately *not* possible. The Forms process itself runs in the Forms Runtime on the server, which is a C program.

You can include a JavaBean as Jeffrey suggests, but the JavaBean will open it's own connection through JDBC - it will not share the transaction context of the Form.

There might be other ways - try updating the question with some details on what you are trying to achieve and I'll be happy to try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is restricted, possible because of security concerns.